# Error in android documentation 'Stopping and Restarting an Activity'

Tags: android

Above mentioned documentation at(http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) states following:

> There are a few of key scenarios in which your activity is stopped and
>   restarted:
>
> The user opens the Recent Apps window and switches from your app to
>   another app. The activity in your app that's currently in the
>   foreground is stopped. If the user returns to your app from the Home
>   screen launcher icon or the Recent Apps window, the activity restarts.

But during debugging I found that overridden `onStop()` in my activity is called when I launch Recent Apps window. So merely launching this window would make activity stop, not that user need to switch to another app as is currently stated in documentation.

Is this an Android documentation error?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming *questions*. What is your *question*? If you wish to file a bug report for the Android SDK documentation, do that here: http://b.android.com.

Comment: Ah...ok.I just wanted to confirm that do others also think same about the issue or my understanding is wrong.

Comment: OPinions are off topic too

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not an error - the last sentence in that dot point states:

> **If the user returns to your app from** the Home screen launcher icon or **the Recent Apps window, the activity restarts.**

(Bold type mine)

stating (a tad awkwardly) that the activity would restart if the user returns from the Recent Apps window, implying that launching the Recent Apps window would stop the activity.

Which is stated a bit in the caption:

> When the user leaves your activity, the system calls `onStop()` to stop the activity

So, by going to the Recent Apps window, you have left the activity, thus the system calls `onStop()`